# Webview not loading from 2nd page

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi i am trying to build a app with a 2 pages main page and another page have a webview so my problem is when i call the 2nd page webview not get call

page 2 have

```
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView x:Name="webview1" Source="https://www.google.com/" />
        </StackLayout>
```

main page

```
    private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new webview());
        }
```

Comment: crash with happening because of Device.StartTimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding HeightRequest and WidthRequest or probably set VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" on your webView. So the code will be :
`<WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="https://www.google.co.in/"/>`

Comment: thanks it worked with FillAndExpand i have tried with HeightRequest and WidthRequest  and didn't work

Comment: Well it should word with HeightRequest as well. Try setting it up something like HeightRequest=1000 and then check.